# How can I implement online high score in LibGDX?

Tags: libgdx, leaderboards

I found some posts that said to use Google Play Services.
What about other platforms? Is their some libgdx library that I can use to implement it in core section or do I need to write separate score implementation to each platform?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using App42 JAVA SDK? Here[http://api.shephertz.com/tutorial/Getting-Started-Java/?index=gs-javasdk&sdk=java] is the documentation for the same and then simply use leaderboard API documentation to implement leaderboards[http://api.shephertz.com/app42-docs/leaderboard-service/?sdk=java] in your libGDX games.

Comment: This answer is a link-only answer which is not very valuable, as links rot.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you know of a third-party service for leader boards that can be used on all devices, you'll have to write platform specific code. The wiki has a [tutorial](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) on that.

Comment: Can I create online DB and work with it using java?

Comment: Of course you can, but you should weight the costs and benefits of each option.

Comment: OK, and what are the costs and benefits of each option?

It's very strange that libgdx doesn't have leaderboard support...

Comment: The costs of having your own server for player stats are that it needs money for maintenance and you have to write both server- and client-side code. The costs of writing platform specific code are that you have multiple implementations that may not behave exactly the same.

Comment: If you don't want to purchase a server, have the knowledges for server-side coding and have an unused PC at home, install Ubuntu on it, configure a MySql database and write your own server. If you can't afford it, search on google, there are a bunch of services for leaderboars (I personally know [Nugetta](http://www.nuggeta.com) )